# Background color of questions

Tags: support

Why is the background color of some questions like the following?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because some of their tags are in your favourites list.

And if it is search result, then some of the tags not presented in search query is in your favourites list.

Comment: but in the middle question also there is jquery tag..so why this question is not highlight?

Comment: @sagarkodte, 2nd sentence. If it is search query by [jquery] tag, the question is highlited only if there is at least one other tag from your favourites.

Comment: ..got it now..:) Thanks...

Comment: yes but why negetive marking..because i saw other answers but not understood..

Comment: @sagarkodte, I upvoted your question. Seems like it's the only upvote.

Comment: oky...no problme

Answer (score 2):

The highlighted posts are those with tags you have selected as your favorite tags.

Comment: but in the middle question also there is jquery tag..so why this question is not highlight?